# In app purchase promo codes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

As I read few articles earlier this year that apple is testing promo codes for in app purchase, is it released by the apple? I can't seem to find any option for in app purchase promo codes in itunes connect neither can find any help regarding it. I want implementing a system for this as my last option, but still if I have to implement it, how can I complete a SKPaymentTransaction programmatically without paying?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a programming question or not. Are you asking about coding/implementation of in-app purchases? If so, could you please clarify the question and [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) it appropriately. If not, perhaps you'd have better luck asking this on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @GoBusto well it has many things to do with programming (I am a programmer and want to implement this and thats why asking), if it is not provided by the apple directly, then people who have implemented this sort of functionality in freemium games might help by explaining there flow. It is tagged iOS and in app purchase both, what else do you expect objective-c? well it is kind of clear from iOS that it might be either objective-c or swift, but for your convenience, I will add objective-C ;)

Answer (score -2):

From Apple:

> Promo codes don’t work for In-App Purchase products

Comment: Can you link me to the docs that says this? AFAIK its allowed, that's why they have a "In-App Purchase Promocodes" section under iTunesConnect Promocode tab. http://imgur.com/a/Dmbd2

Comment: Looks like they released this on 28th Oct 2016. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10282016a